# how to access an html element properly using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

well here is my html code

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>first page</title> 
<script style="text/css" src=".\Scripts\CSS\tryc.css"></script> 
<script style="text/javascript" src=".\Scripts\JavaScripts\Text8.js"></script> 
</head> 
<body id="body">
<hi id="heading1">Coming Soon<h1> 
<object id="circle-svg" width="1300" height="560" type="image/svg+xml"data=".\Scripts\svg\ulti.svg"></object> 
</body> 
</html>
```

---

and my java script is

```
var as=document.getElementById("body"); alert(as); alert("try");
```

---

i dont know why it is not givving any alerts...

Comment: what directory is your javascript in?  It sounds like your js file may not be where you think it is.

Comment: Your title seems largely unrelated to your question.

Comment: hmmm @Chethan N thing worked....i dont have the explanation

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var as=document.getElementById("body"); 
   alert(as); 
   alert("try");
};
```

Alert it one the page is loaded.

In javascript you catch an event and tell the browser what action to do when that event occurs. In your code there is no event, so it will not be executed. In the code above window.onload is caught and the function is triggered one the event occurs.

Comment: can you explain a little why it didnt work earlier

Comment: I have updated the answer explaining why your code didn't work initially.

Comment: and then i changed the code a little ::
window.onload = function() {
  var as=document.getElementById("body"); 
  var as1=as.getElementById("heading1"); 
  as1.style.color="blue";
   alert(as1); 
   alert("try");
};

can you pls tell why its not working now...

Comment: That should work fine!

Comment: the Coming Soon is not becoming blue!!!
and it tells
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLBodyElement> has no method 'getElementById'